# Pass username and password in URL to PHP page?

Tags: php, authentication

I have deployed a simple PHP-based application (http://www.bigprof.com/appgini/) on my local network. I would like a way to implement a way for users to automatically log in. Security is a non-issue. Would it be possible to modify the login page to accept something like http://user:pass@app.server.lan/?

[This is the source of the login page](http://pastebin.com/kZ7t3hFA), if that helps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask, out of curiosity? Why or how is security not an issue for your app?

Comment: It's always an "issue" but I don't want my team to have to store/manage another set of credentials. I'd rather generate something complex and store it in a bookmark on their already secure desktops.

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP Basic Auth credentials are available in PHP in the [`$_SERVER` superglobal in the keys `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW`.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

From http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

For more sophisticated ways of doing authentication check out

- http://pear.php.net/package/Auth or
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html

Answer (score 3):

http://user:pass@app.server.lan/ is using by htaccess auth

instead of it you can use,

http://app.server.lan/?user=user&pass=pass

after login redirect to

http://app.server.lan/

**.htacccess**

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/password/file/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Members Area"
AuthType "Basic"

<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Comment: Well, I kind of understand, but I don't have a .htaccess file in the directory that this app uses.... It's really http://app.server.lan/app

Comment: @AaronJAnderson htaccess is an old auth, i think you use `$_GET['user']` & `$_GET['pass']` method which create link like `http://app.server.lan/?user=user&pass=pass`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted way to automatically login to a website is using the "remember me" feature. Use cookies for that. Do you need help to implement it?

And Security always is an issue, specially if you share the hosting (You can compromise the whole server).

Answer (score 0):

In response to @AaronJAnderson's comment about being open to another solution I'd like to suggest:

http://alpho011.hubpages.com/hub/Use-Windows-Login-in-PHP-Applications

Of course, that's assuming you are on a windows-based network, have a domain and a proper network set up, and have access to LDAP (and later Active Directory, if ever)

It isn't that long of an article and it has code; hope you can look into this as posting sensitive information in URLs can still be dangerous on a peer to peer level even if you're on a secured network domain.. :(

[edit] in response to @AaronJAnderson's comment on integration:

Create a login form to accept the username and password of your user, and when the form is submitted, use [`ldap_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) to connect to your domain.. And then if successful, use [`ldap_bind`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php) to submit the username (to which you append the domain using `@whateverdomain`) and password to your ldap host (if you don't have this info you can ask your system/server admins for help) --if successful then you've confirmed that the user provided the right username and password. It's mostly there in the article, but I've also placed links on `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind`. I hope this can help.

Comment: I like this a lot. I'm not sure I understand how to integrate it. Doesn't the application need to know about the user account? Does it need to tie into ldap as well?

Comment: @AaronJAnderson , I've updated my post and entered some more information. :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1Va79GFB

I got this to bind to LDAP... But I am still totally lost on how to make it work with the application I'm using. Doesn't the app need to know that my account "domain\user" is allow to use it?

Comment: @AaronJAnderson , I checked your code from this link (in your original post) http://pastebin.com/kZ7t3hFA and it appears to be the returned HTML code.. What you should look for is the PHP source code that processes the posted form username and password. Now it may seem that you still require your users to 'submit' login information through a form, it would still be better than posting it in the url, where the password is not masked..

Comment: This is the full php file... Do you think it's possible to integrate what we talked about into this, somehow? 

http://pastebin.com/QAxW1eA9

Comment: @AaronJAnderson, I've got just a few minutes to spare so I created this chat room. Please head here as soon as you can: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5383/pass-username-and-password-in-url-to-php-page

Comment: I'm too new here to use the chat. I need more reputation. :( - Anyway that file IS index.php. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Upvoted.. now that you have enough to join a chat.. please go here, @AaronJAnderson : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5383/pass-username-and-password-in-url-to-php-page and we can continue from there,